# Using Placeholders Within NSDictionary Strings On iOS

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsdictionary, placeholder

I am trying to make a dictionary for Facebook posting, and trying to figure out how to use placeholders in my string.  I currently have:

```
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"message" : @"I'm reading today.", @"caption": (@"I'm on %@", _entry.date), @"link": _entry.articleUrl};
```

_entry.date is a string that displays which day of reading the user is on, and _entry.articleUrl is a string for the page the user is reading.  My issue is getting the correct format so that the string used for caption can have text and a placeholder for the string.  Right now it tells me the expression result is unused.

Comment: Are you trying to build a string from a format by wrapping it in parentheses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this string api to build your string:

```
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"message" : @"I'm reading today.", @"caption": [NSString stringWithFormat:@"I'm on %@", _entry.date], @"link": _entry.articleUrl};
```

Comment: Perfect.  Knew it had to be something like that, just couldn't get it down correct.